# Open a page after click on notification using ionic and firebase cloud messaging

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

Good evening. I am trying to  handle notification click in such a way that when the user click on a notification, a specific page of my application is opened. 
I am using **FIREBASE COULD MESSAGING AND IONIC 3**

Here is the code of the app.component.ts file in witch the code for handling notification is written :

```
import { Platform, Nav, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm';

import { Signup } from '../pages/signup/signup';

   @Component({
      templateUrl: 'app.html',
      selector: 'Myappname',
   })
   export class MyApp {

        @ViewChild(Nav) nv: Nav;

        rootPage: any = HomePage;

        constructor(public fcm: FCM, platform: Platform) {

          platform.ready().then(() => {

                  fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {

                         if (data.wasTapped) {

                              this.nv.push(Signup);

                         } else {

                           console.log("Received in foreground");

                         }
                 })
         });
    }
 }
```

When the nofication is received on the mobile device, if the user click on it, only the home page is displayed and he is note redirected to the signup page as specified in the code.

Any helps ?
Thanks.

Comment: hi @THE HOLLY SPIRIT i am also ahaving a sample u find any solution for that in my case data tapped always show false any solution

Comment: Hello @jose make sure that in your payload object, the clickAction property is set to FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution. as i was using firebase cloud functions to send the notification, here is the code i used to make the onNotification() work when a user click on the notification received.

```
exports.Hello = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}').onCreate(event=>{

         admin.messaging().sendToTopic('all', {
              data:{
                 "key1": value1,
                 "key2": value2
              },
              notification: {
                  clickAction : "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
                  sound : "default",
                  title : "Notification title",
                  body : "message content"
              }
         });

});
```

So We must set **clickAction** property of the **notification** object to **FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY** to make **onNotification()** method execute when the user tapped on the notification.

Here is a code exemple for the **app.component.ts** in witch the **onNotification()** method is implemented.

```
  import { Platform, Nav, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

  import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

  import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

  import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm';

  import { Signup } from '../pages/signup/signup';

  @Component({
        templateUrl: 'app.html',
        selector: 'Myappname',
  })
  export class MyApp {

    @ViewChild(Nav) nv: Nav;

    rootPage: any = HomePage;

    constructor(public fcm: FCM, platform: Platform) {

      platform.ready().then(() => {

              fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {

                     if (data.wasTapped) {

                          this.nv.push(Signup);

                     } else {

                       console.log("Received in foreground");

                     }
             })
           });
      }
  }
```

AND now, it works fine !

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the root page as the signup page, hopefully it will work:

```
this.nv.setRoot(Signup);
```

and if that doesnt work try adding this before your fcm.onNotification()

```
var $this = this;
```

and then use $this to reference inside your if statement // (wasTapped)

```
$this.nv.setRoot(Signup);
```

Comment: Hello @Mahesh. i tried it the two options but it does not work.

Comment: Can you just remove that assignment of rootPage=homepage and then check if that works when you receive notification

Comment: Can you try this one last thing try to set the rootPage as signupPage inside tapped this.rootPage=signup and inside constructor set rootPage=homepage and check where are you getting redirected after you get notification homepage or signupPage

Comment: If it is homepage without errors I will suggest one solution

Comment: Hello @mahesh. I found the solution. please see the answer. And manys thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh yes I thought you are able to enter inside the wasTapped you should have informed that you are not able to enter the on Notification method only..anyways glad it worked

Comment: HELLO @mahesh. in fact actually when the user click n the notification, the user is no more redirected to the Signup page.

Comment: Is your code working or still your having some issue

Comment: what is the solution to this, please guide